# Jmeter: What is the difference between [Thread: 50, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 1] and [Thread: 1, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 50] in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

What is the difference between 
[Thread: 50, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 1] 
and 
[Thread: 1, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 50]
Both are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **NOT** the same

JMeter acts as follows:

- It starts number of threads (virtual users) within the time frame defined in ramp-up period.
- Threads start executing samplers upside-down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
- When there are no samplers to execute and loops to iterate - threads are being shut down.

See [Elements of a Test Plan - Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) chapter for more information

1. `[Thread: 50, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 1]` - JMeter will start **50 threads** which will execute samplers **1 time**
2. `[Thread: 1, Ramp-Period: 0, Loop: 50]` - JMeter will start **1 thread** which will execute samplers **50 times**

Actual concurrency is a big question mark as it strongly dependent on what threads need to do and how many loops are there.

- If you need to simulate 50 virtual users - provide enough loops
- If you need to simulate 50 requests per second load:

  - provide enough loops
  - provide enough threads (at least twice as more)
  - use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to set desired requests per minute rate